How can I fix 'PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in' error in my PHP code?
I get the following errors in the theme file on a website with Wordpress installed. This error appeared when I upgraded to PHP 8.1
2 line error logs :

PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in ...


PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ...

Code is :
    <?php
if ($options['logo']['url'] != 'null'){
echo '<img class="img-fluid imglogo" src="'
.$options['logo']['url'].'" width="'
.$options['logo']['width'].'" height="'
.$options['logo']['height'].'" alt="'
.get_bloginfo('name').'" />';
}
?>


what is the value in $options?

Just like in any other situation, check for whether the variables exist and are valid before you try to use them. Which of your array elements / program lines are the error messages pointing to?

These errors occurs in latest PHP versins. You can fix these by adding type checks to ensure $options['logo'] is a valid array before accessing its elements:
<?php
if (isset($options['logo']) && is_array($options['logo']) && isset($options['logo']['url']) && $options['logo']['url'] !== 'null') {
    echo '<img class="img-fluid imglogo" src="'
    . $options['logo']['url'] . '" width="'
    . $options['logo']['width'] . '" height="'
    . $options['logo']['height'] . '" alt="'
    . get_bloginfo('name') . '" />';
}
?>


isset($options['logo']['url']) is enough
